# How to log in Scala *without* a reference to the logger in *every instance*?

Tags: scala, logging, singleton

I've looked at example of logging in Scala, and it usually looks like this:

```
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

trait Loggable {
  private lazy val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass)
  protected def debug(msg: => AnyRef, t: => Throwable = null): Unit =
    {...}
}
```

This seems independent of the concrete logging framework. While this does the job, it also introduces an extraneous lazy val *in every instance* that wants to do logging, which might well be every instance of the whole application. This seems much too heavy to me, in particular if you have many "small instances" of some specific type.

Is there a way of putting the logger in the object of the concrete class instead, just by using inheritance? If I have to explicitly declare the logger in the object of the class, and explicitly refer to it from the class/trait, then I have written almost as much code as if I had done no reuse at all.

Expressed in a non-logging specific context, the problem would be:

How do I declare in a trait that the implementing class must have a singleton object of type X, and that this singleton object must be accessible through method def x: X ?

I can't simply define an abstract method, because there could only be a single implementation in the class. I want that logging in a super-class gets me the super-class singleton, and logging in the sub-class gets me the sub-class singleton. Or put more simply, I want logging in Scala to work like traditional logging in Java, using static loggers specific to the class doing the logging. My current knowledge of Scala tells me that this is simply not possible without doing it exactly the same way you do in Java, without much if any benefits from using the "better" Scala.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How do I declare in a trait that the
>   implementing class must have a
>   singleton object of type X, and that
>   this singleton object must be
>   accessible through method def x: X ?

Declare a trait that must be implemented by your companion objects.

```
trait Meta[Base] {
  val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass)
}
```

Create a base trait for your classes, sub-classes have to overwrite the meta method.

```
trait Base {
  def meta: Meta[Base]
  def logger = meta.logger
}
```

A class Whatever with a companion object:

```
object Whatever extends Meta[Base]

class Whatever extends Base {
  def meta = Whatever

  def doSomething = {
    logger.log("oops")
  }
}
```

In this way you only need to have a reference to the meta object.

We can use the Whatever class like this.

```
object Sample {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val whatever = new Whatever
    whatever.doSomething
  }
}
```

Comment: If class SomethingElse extend class Whatever, and override meta to point to it's own singleton, then suddenly doSomething will log to that singleton, and if SomethingElse doesn't, then SomethingElse's log output will go to Whatever's singleton. In "traditional" static Java logging, the log output is statically bound, so when you see a message, you know in which class to look for it. Not so in your solution.

Comment: Is that so much of a problem though? As I understand this, you can inherit or override, both are reasonable. doSomething doesn't suddenly log to its own singleton, it does so only when you have explicitly asked it to by overriding meta.

Answer (score 16):

## Premature Optimization is the root of all evil

Let's be clear first about one thing: if your trait looks something like this:

```
trait Logger { lazy val log = Logger.getLogger }
```

Then what you have **not** done is as follows:

- You have **NOT** created a logger instance per instance of your type
- You have neither given yourself a memory nor a performance problem (unless you have)

What you *have* done is as follows:

- You have an extra *reference* in each instance of your type
- When you access the logger for the first time, you are probably doing some map lookup

Note that, *even if you did create a separate logger for each instance of your type* (which I frequently do, even if my program contains hundreds of thousands of these, so that I have very fine-grained control over my logging), you almost certainly still *will neither have a performance nor a memory problem*!

---

One "solution" is (of course), to make the companion object implement the logger interface:

```
object MyType extends Logger

class MyType {
  import MyType._
  log.info("Yay")
}
```

Comment: I have not said that every instance get it's own logger object, because no logging framework that I ever heard of does that. Since they are normally statically initialized, they accept the slightly higher cost of using some kind of map inside the factory which is why no one does "new Logger". I was talking all along about the *reference*. The sentence "extraneous lazy val in every instance" simply means "extraneous lazy final reference in every instance".

Comment: I did not say that you had said that. But your concern for waste I felt did warrant the clarification as to what the cost of this was. That is: minimal. Almost non-existent in fact. For a million objects, we're talking 8-16Mb of extra space.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question completely. So I apologize up front if this is not the answer you are looking for.

Define an `object` were you put your `logger` into, then create a companion `trait`.

```
object Loggable {
   private val logger = "I'm a logger"
}

trait Loggable {
   import Loggable._
   def debug(msg: String) {
      println(logger + ": " + msg)
   }
}
```

So now you can use it like this:

```
scala> abstract class Abstraction
scala> class Implementation extends Abstraction with Loggable
scala> val test = new Implementation
scala> test.debug("error message")
I'm a logger: error message
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: With this solution, either every class logs using the same logger, or every class has to redefine the debug() ... methods to use different loggers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot automatically get the corresponding singleton object of a class or require that such a singleton exists.

One reason is that you cannot know the type of the singleton before it is defined. Not sure, if this helps or if it is the best solution to your problem, but if you want to require some meta object to be defined with a specific trait, you could define something like:

```
trait HasSingleton[Traits] {
  def meta: Traits
}

trait Log {
  def classname: String
  def log { println(classname) }
}

trait Debug {
  def debug { print("Debug") }
}

class A extends HasSingleton[Log] {
  def meta = A // Needs to be defined with a Singleton (or any object which inherits from Log}
  def f {
    meta.log
  }
}
object A extends Log {
  def classname = "A"
}

class B extends HasSingleton[Log with Debug] { // we want to use Log and Debug here
  def meta = B
  def g {
    meta.log
    meta.debug
  }
}
object B extends Log with Debug {
  def classname = "B"
}

(new A).f
// A
(new B).g
// B
// Debug
```

Comment: Your solution suffers from the same problem as the one from Stefan De Boey.

Comment: Hmm, if you want to have it statically bound, you should probably write it statically.